# Bounds for solving systems of linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw somewhere, a long time ago that if a system of linear inequalities is solvable then it has a solution within a bound which is simply computed from the coefficients of the system. This is important as it allows algorithm to be restricted to the bounded case without loss of generality. Can anyone tell me about this bound, I cannot remember the reference? Thanks